# Is there a possibility to receive several AJAX responses from PHP server simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I want to make a progress bar on my website, which tracks execution of a PHP script.

The PHP script makes a bunch of connections with Google API and stores the data it receives in the database. Sometimes the process can take a minute.

The PHP script is located in `ajax/integrations-ajax.php` file and launched by GET AJAX request sent, if on the website to click `#link` button. Below is jQuery code for the request:

```
$('#link').on('click', function () {
    var interval = setInterval(trackStatus, 1000);
    $.getJSON('ajax/integrations-ajax.php', {action: 'link'}).done(function (json) {            
        if (json.result == true) {
            showMessage('The account is successfully linked.', 'success');
        } else {
            showMessage('There is an error happened.', 'danger');
        }
    })
});
```

This `#link` button, also sets interval which fires `trackStatus` function each second:

```
function trackStatus() {
    $.getJSON('ajax/status-ajax.php', { 
        action: 'status'
    }).done(function (json) {
        console.log(json.status);
    });
}
```

As you can see, `trackStatus` function sends GET AJAX requests to `ajax/status-ajax.php` file and should show status in browser console every second.

To implement tracking ability on the server I made the PHP script in `ajax/integrations-ajax.php` file to store status in the database. Its code you can see below:

```
<?php
if(!is_ajax_request()) { exit; }
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? (string) $_GET['action'] : '';
if ($action == 'link') {
    set_status_in_database(0);
    // some execution code;

    set_status_in_database(1);
    // some execution code;

    set_status_in_database(2);
    // some execution code;

    set_status_in_database(3);
    // some execution code;
    echo json_encode(['result' => true ]);
}
```

And created another PHP file `axax/status-ajax.php` which can recover the status from the database:

```
<?php
if(!is_ajax_request()) { exit; }
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? (string) $_GET['action'] : '';
if ($action == 'status') {
    $return['result'] = get_status_from_database();
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

But the requests appear not to be working simultaneously. I can't receive responses for `trackStatus` function until the response on completion `ajax/integrations-ajax.php` script isn't received.

I made a profiling record in browser, which show that:
[image]

So, is there a possibility to execute requests simultaneously? Or to implement the tracking ability I need to rethink the whole approach?

Thanks in advance for help!

---

**Update**
Thank you all for your advice! And especially to @Keith, because his solution is the easiest and works. I have put session_write_close() function in the beginning for the script and everything works:

```
<?php
if(!is_ajax_request()) { exit; }
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? (string) $_GET['action'] : '';
if ($action == 'link') {
    session_write_close();
    set_status_in_database(0);
    // some execution code;

    set_status_in_database(1);
    // some execution code;

    set_status_in_database(2);
    // some execution code;

    set_status_in_database(3);
    // some execution code;
    echo json_encode(['result' => true ]);
}
```

Here you can see profiling record from a browser:
[image]

Comment: I'm not a PHP guru, so somebody else might have a better solution.  But PHP places exclusive locks on session data, so this could be serializing your Ajax requests.  Try and call `session_write_close` as soon as you can & this will release the lock. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: might consider a web socket. You can make 1 second get requests to the server and you should return a very short response. Maybe just send back `20%` or or `{ "status": 20}` (for a JSON result).

Comment: In short, you can run and recieve requests simultaneously using javascript, and I think the issue relies on your php service being locked like @Keith mentioned

Comment: The OP isn’t relying on PHP sessions at all, but rather dB.

Comment: May want to examine https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html

Comment: Thank you @Keith! Your advice works! I put session_write_close() in the beginning for the code and everything works!

Comment: Nice one, I'll knock up a quick answer in case others come across.

Comment: @Amjo  Even if you don't use PHP Sessions it appears a lock is still placed.  If you don't use sessions at all, there is maybe a config setting you can change.  Not used PHP for years, switched to Node.js, and then never looked back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While PHP can handle concurrent requests without issue, one area that does get serialized is the Session, basically PHP during a request will place an exclusive lock on the SESSION, for that user.  IOW: While this lock is on, other requests from the same user will have to wait.  This is normally not an issue, but if you have long running requests it will block other requests, like AJax requests etc.

As a default PHP will write session data at then end off the request,.  But if you are sure you no longer need to write any session data, calling `session_write_close` will release the lock much sooner.

More info here -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Thank you @Keith! Your solution is the easiest and works. I have put session_write_close() function in the beginning for the script and everything works. You can see profiling record from a browser: [Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/H5bYmJKl95uErg)

Answer (score 2):

Would advise trying [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource). Here is an example.

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
// recommended to prevent caching of event data.
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

function send_message($id, $message, $progress) {
  $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress);
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: " . json_encode($d) . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}

for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
  set_status_in_database($i);
  // some execution code;
  send_message($i, "set status in database " . $i + 1 . " of 3' , $i*4);
  sleep(1);
}

send_message('CLOSE', 'Process complete');
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var es;

function startTask() {
  es = new eventSource('ajax/status-ajax.php');
  es.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(result.message);
    if(e.lastEventId == 'CLOSE') {
      console.log('Received CLOSE closing');
      es.close();
      showMessage('The account is successfully linked.', 'success');
    } else {
      $('.progress').css("width", result.progress + '%');
    }
  });
  es.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Error occurred', e);
    es.close();
  });
}

function stopTask() {
  es.close();
  console.log('Interrupted');
}

$('#link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  startTask($(this));
});
```

Reference:

- [Show Progress Report for Long-running PHP Scripts](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html)

Hope that is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Both php logic and JavaScript syntax seem to be fine; however, with the minimal amount of php code example it is assumed that it’s resource heavy. MySQL might be busy, which is why **get status** may wait for MySQL.

I have gone around such a problem by making the *update status* **written to a file** instead of competing for database resources.

Answer (score 0):

Since you consider using a different approach, let me recommend [GraphQL](http://graphql.org) as a thin layer / api above your database.

There are quite a few Php-solutions out there, for example [Siler](https://siler.leocavalcante.com/graphql/). Look for one that has [subscriptions](https://siler.leocavalcante.com/graphql/subscriptions.html) (not all do), as this would be the feature you are looking for. Subscriptions are used to create a websocket (stream between your Php and Javascript), reducing all status-related communication to one call.

Yes, this may be "shooting cannons at birds", but maybe you have other things flying around, then it might be worth considering. There is a [fantastic document](https://www.howtographql.com/) to familiarize with the intriguing concept. You'd be able to reuse most of your database-related Php within the [resolver functions](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers).